# setup_exception_record error when running wine application

Tags: wine

I am using wine 1.3.28 and when i run leagueoflegends.exe i am getting this

```
antonis@antonis-desktop:~/Downloads$ wine leagueoflegends.exe
err:seh:setup_exception_record stack overflow 1696 bytes in thread 0009 eip 7ef6dc3b esp 00ab0c90 stack 0xab0000-0xab1000-0xcb0000
Segmentation fault
```

Can anyone tell me what this means? Thank you for your time

Answer (score 3):

That means that League of Legends doesn't run under wine, as it's [appdb entry](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=19141) shows.

If you are interested in what this message really means, you can get much more info running it under the [wine debugger](http://www.winehq.org/docs/winedev-guide/wine-debugger), but note that this is a quite complex task and you will need a good knowledge of both linux and windows programming.